# SQL error on PostgreSQL database on Heroku - can't run update

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I need to run an update query over a database I have set up on a rails site on heroku. Its a simple query however for some reason when I try to run the sql from the sql console i.e `Heroku sql` I get a syntax error. I don't know whats wrong with the sql it seems fine to me:

```
SQL> UPDATE service_types SET desc = replace(desc, ' Charge', '');
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "desc"
LINE 1: UPDATE service_types SET desc = replace(desc, ' Charge', '')...
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escape it using double quotes (*the easiest way, i know there's another*)

```
UPDATE service_types SET "desc" = replace("desc", ' Charge', '');
```

- [PostgreSQL Reserved Keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

<strike>or assign an ALIAS</strike>

```
UPDATE service_types a SET a.desc = replace(a.desc, ' Charge', '');
```

Comment: @JW. Renaming the column (to e.g. `descr`) is probably better in the long run though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I definitely agrees with you. I was just assuming that he cannot alter the tables. Anyway great comment. using reserved keyword will give pain in the neck in the future. `:D`

Comment: ouch so desc is a reserved keyword here - I didnt know that - thanks for the tip! Time for some major database refactoring

Comment: @Ali: It's the indicator whether you want to sort ascending or descending: `select .. order by some_col desc`.